# how to execute emit after the function is called on the same event

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I have 2 components main component to view image and child component to take input image from user. when the user uploads an image its supposed to view image on main(parent) component at the same time instead of clicking on some other button ( my older way to view it).

right now what happening is when I upload an image the previous image is displaying.

```
<v-file-input @change="uploadImage($event), $emit('setImg',previewImage)"> </v-file-input>
```

for better understanding check the link below

[vuetify playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

I have tried using next() , then(), calling $emit in function but so far no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to wait with the emit until the base64 image is loaded.

In the template, remove the emit:

```html
    <input
      type="file"
      accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/bmp"
      @change="uploadImage($event)"
    />
```

In `uploadImage($event)`, emit the base64 image when it has loaded:

```
      async uploadImage(e) {
        const image = e.target.files[0]
        const reader = new FileReader()
        reader.readAsDataURL(image)
        const loadEvent = await new Promise(resolve => reader.onload = resolve)
        this.previewImage = loadEvent.target.result
        this.$emit('setImg', this.previewImage)
        console.log(this.previewImage)
      },
```

Have a look at the [updated playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)